# How to use media queries in mail clients

Tags: email, mobile, media, tablet

How can i use media queries in mail clients because it is not working nothing is changing on mobile/tablet view. I have tried putting media queries in css but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Not all email clients support media queries. Make sure you're testing in an email client that do support them. You can refer to [caniemail.com](https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-at-media/) to check for support.

[image: Can I email… @media]